# How to fix error: (psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation) null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Why is the error below occurring? I am aware of the `db.session.add()` method however I want to use raw SQL for learning sake. Shouldn't the UUID be auto-generating? Maybe I am missing something in the postgresql text or have the id not correct in the model?

**error**

```
Error: (psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation) null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, testuser, email@test.com, pASsWorD, null, 2021-01-10 16:13:23.270353-08).
```

**models.py**

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID
from sqlalchemy import DateTime
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

from .. import db

class Users(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(
        UUID(as_uuid=True),
        primary_key=True,
        unique=True,
    )
    username = db.Column(
        db.String(120),
        unique=True,
        nullable=False
    )
    email = db.Column(
        db.String(120),
        unique=True,
        nullable=False
    )
    password = db.Column(
        db.String(120),
        nullable=False
    )
    updated_at = db.Column(
        DateTime(timezone=True),
        onupdate=func.now()
    )
    created_at = db.Column(
        DateTime(timezone=True),
        server_default=func.now()
    )
```

**api.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint, request, jsonify
from sqlalchemy import text, exc
from types import SimpleNamespace
from ...models.users import db, Users

bp = Blueprint('api', __name__, url_prefix='/api/v1')

@bp.route('/users', methods=['POST'])
def users():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            response = dict(request.get_json())
            values = SimpleNamespace(**response)

            if all(response.values()):
                sql_insert_one = text(f"INSERT INTO users(username, email, password) VALUES ('{values.username}', '{values.email}', '{values.password}');")
                db.session.execute(sql_insert_one)
                db.session.commit()
                message = f"successfully added new user: {values.username}"
            else:
                message = f"error adding new user, values submitted: {values}"

            return jsonify(response)
        except Exception as err:
            print(f'Error: {err}') 
            return jsonify(f'"error":"{err}"')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question "shouldn't the UUID be auto-generating?" No. From the postgresql docs: 'the core database does not include any function for generating UUIDs' [ref](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-uuid.html).

You need to generate the UUID yourself, try [uuid](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html).

Or you can use `db.Integer` instead of `db.UUID` and SQLAlchemy will make it a sequence and it will auto-generate the `id` value.

Comment: `sql_insert_one = text(f"INSERT INTO users(id, username, email, password) VALUES ('{uuid.uuid4().hex}', '{values.username}', '{values.email}', '{values.password}');")` worked, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In My case, everything is fine from the code level. But when I cross-checks the table DDL query(Structure), Autoincrement is not available in table level.

```
CREATE TABLE public.example_table (
id int4 NOT NULL,
table_name varchar(100) NULL,
created_at timestamptz(6) NOT NULL,
created_by_id int4 NULL,
CONSTRAINT "example_table_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

);

It should be

```
CREATE TABLE public.example_table (
id serial NOT NULL,
table_name varchar(100) NULL,
created_at timestamptz(6) NOT NULL,
created_by_id int4 NULL,
CONSTRAINT "example_table_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

);

Make sure your table structure.
It may helpful for someone