# SQLAlchemy Error '(psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation) null value in column "id" of relation

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am aware of a similar issue [How to fix error: (psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation) null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65659966/how-to-fix-error-psycopg2-errors-notnullviolation-null-value-in-column-id-v) but the answers there did not fix my error

I have the following sqlalchemy structure connected to a postgres database

```
class Injury(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "injury"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    description = Column(String)
```

The DDL looks like

```
create table injury
(
    id               bigint not null
        constraint idx_182837_injury_pkey
            primary key
        constraint injury_id_key
            unique,
    name             text,
    description      text,
);
```

However, upon trying to insert something into the database like the following

```
injury = Injury(name='name', description='desc')
session.add(injury)
session.commit()
```

The following error occurs

```
Error '(psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation) null value in column "id" of relation "injury" violates not-null constraint
```

Upon opening up my debugger, I can verify that the `id` attribute in the `injury` object before I commit is `None`

Why is this occurring? Shouldn't `primary_key=True` in my schema tell postgres that it is responsible for making the id? I tried playing around with `SEQUENCE` and `IDENTITY` but I was getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a result of some form of bug during my transfer from sqlite to postgres when I used `pg_loader`. I found out someone else [encountered this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45295445/16179502) and I followed their instructions and it corrected my issue. The following steps were all done in IntelliJ's database tool

- Exported all of my data out with pg_dump
- Reformatted my id schema to look like `id = Column(Integer, Identity(start=2116), primary_key=True)` where 2116 is one more than the last id i currently have in my database
- Reloaded data base in with pg_loader

This was working without the `Identity` field but the key was set to 1 instead of 2116. Looking at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67018684/sqlalchemy-exc-integrityerror-duplicate-key-value-violates-unique-constraint-u) helped me realize I needed to use the `Identity` field.

Answer (score 1):

you have to tell it to auto increment
dont use bigint but serial

```
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
```

check this [how-to-define-an-auto-increment-primary-key-in-postgresql-using-python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-define-an-auto-increment-primary-key-in-postgresql-using-python/)

Comment: Thank you, this led me down the correct path